# Only show object with same attribute in controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

```
<%= link_to categorization_path(categorization: :adventure) do %>    
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture", id="challenge-category"></span>
<% end %>
# There are other categories such as health, work, wacky, etc
```

routes.rb

```
get ":categorization", to: "pages#home", as: 'categorization'
```

At this point if a user click on the above `link_to` I want to only show challenges with the attribute of `categorization: adventure`.

What do I need to put in `pages#home` to make this work?

pages_controller.rb

```
def home
 @challenges = current_user.challenges.order("deadline ASC")
 #How to only show one of the :categorization challenges if URL is root_path/:categorization?
end
```

challenge.rb

```
CATEGORIZATION = ['adventure', 'health', 'work', 'buy', 'wacky']
scope :adventure,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Adventure') }
scope :health,  -> { where(categorizations: 'health') }
scope :work,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Work') }
scope :buy,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Buy') }
scope :wacky,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Wacky') }
scope :goal,  -> { where(categories: 'Goal') }
scope :habit,  -> { where(categories: 'Habit') }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to only show one of the :categorization challenges if URL is
>   root_path/:categorization?

Your default `@challenges` already returns an ordered `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. Therefore, you could chain a `scope` to it.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  # 1) using Rails method: `Object#try`
  # http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try
  #
  def home
    # default challenges
    @challenges = current_user.challenges.order("deadline ASC")

    if home_params[:categorization]
      # `try` scope categorization param
      # `try` returns nil if param is invalid
      @challenges = @challenges.try(home_params[:categorization])

      # even if no results, empty AR object still returned
      #   => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
      #
      unless @challenges.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)
        # do whatever here; remove placeholder on next line:
        raise "invalid categorization => #{home_params[:categorization]}"
      end
    end
  end

  # --OR--

  # 2) using Ruby method: `Object#send`
  # http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send
  #
  def home
    # default challenges
    @challenges = current_user.challenges.order("deadline ASC")

    if home_params[:categorization]
      @challenges = @challenges.send(home_params[:categorization])
    end

  rescue NoMethodError
    # do whatever here; remove placeholder on next line:
    raise "invalid categorization => #{home_params[:categorization]}"
  end



  private

  def home_params
    params.permit(:categorization)
  end
end
```

*see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes*

*see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters*

Answer (score 0):

In your action, try replacing the current line by this one:

@challenges = current_user.challenges.send(params[:categorization]).order("deadline ASC")

It should work

Comment: can you post the output of 
logger.debug params
to that action? thks

Comment: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column challenges.categorizations does not exist
LINE 1: ...challenges" WHERE "challenges"."user_id" = $1 AND "challenge...`